# Facebook login button onlogin callback fires twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-login

Per [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button), the html attribute 'onlogin' can be used to run a callback function after a login is complete

However we're consistently getting the supplied function run twice, causing problems when it does actual work.

While we can catch this with a counter of how many times its run I'd rather have an understanding of why this happens and fix it than apply a workaround. The entirety of the code is below (won't run in snippet):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>facebook login test</title>
 <script src="/Vendors/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
    appId      : 'foobar123456', // see https://developers.facebook.com/apps/
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.11' // see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart
   });
   
   FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
   
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>

  <!-- LOGIN BUTTON scope at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/ -->
  <div class="fb-login-button" data-width="250" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" onlogin="fbLoginHandler" data-scope="public_profile,email" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>

  <script>
   console.log("reached script tag");
   var timesfbLoginHandlerFired = 0;
   var fbLoginHandler = ()=>{
    timesfbLoginHandlerFired++;
    console.log("fbLoginHandler fired ["+timesfbLoginHandlerFired+"] times");
   };
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

And the console:

```
Navigated to https://fbtest.dev/fblogin <- on page load
reached script tag <- on page load
XHR finished loading: POST "https://www.facebook.com/ajax/bz". <- on page load
XHR finished loading: POST "https://www.facebook.com/ajax/bz". <- on facebook login prompt window opening
fbLoginHandler fired [1] times <- on login complete
fbLoginHandler fired [2] times <- on login complete
```

Comment: I got the same problem, i think the best solution is to apply manual controls, but a faster solution may be a workaround... i will show you my workaround!

Answer (score 2):

My Faster workaround was as following:

I just set a variable called fblogin_done

```
fblogin_done = 0;
```

And in the function that is being executed twice i put a counter and a blocker with a timer

```
function CheckLoginState() {
    if (fblogin_done == 1) return; // avoid twice executions
    fblogin_done = 1;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        fblogin_done = 0; // wait 1 second after a second execution
    }, 1000);
}
```

A second was enough to me to avoid more than 1 execution,

Answer (score 2):

It seems to have to do with the `data-auto-logout-link` set to `true`.

Setting that to `false`, stops the button from firing the `onlogin` function twice.

Without seeing how the SDK handles it, my best guess is that when the button changes to become a logout button, it must be checking for login and triggering the onlogin function a second time.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a clean way of handling the double call.

```
function mainLogin() {

   FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {   // when connected, login, avoids double call                 
      if (response.status === 'connected') {                        
         fbLogin();
      };
   });
}

function fbLogin() {

   FB.api('/me?fields=name,id,email', function (response) {

      if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(response)) {  //make certain we got a response object
         console.log(response);
         //todo: Get the FB data and process it...

       } else {
          //todo: err handling
       }                
    });
}
```